# Nginx regular expressions `{number}` doesn't work appropriately

Tags: regex, nginx

I want to use `if` statement regular expression on a query string So I code like below.

```
if ($arg_arg1 ~* [A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}) {
                                echo "print something;
                        }
```

But when I reload the configuration, it returns `nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "[A-Z0-9]" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:29`.

Later I fix `[A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}` to `"[A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}"` adding `"`.

Why do I have to enclose `"` ?

Even though I can reload the configuration with `"`

It still has a problem.

It works not as I expect.

It Must follow below rules.

1. exact 3 char ranging A-Z or 0-9
2. 1 char _
3. 1~28 char ranging  " "-~

for example AAA_11, ABC_123123123, EEE_asdasdasd, 123_123123.

But It passes below wrong conditions

aaa_123  (the first three char Must be upper capital)

aaaa_123 (aaaa is more than 3 char)

I tested my regular express on Python code .

```
import re 
r = re.match("[A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}", "123_aaa")
print r.string
```

Comment: You need quotes, because nginx's parser quite simple and `{` always means start of block body unless it's placed into quotes.

Comment: How did you check regexp? You regexp is quite strange. What should it match?

Comment: @Alexey Ten , It will match `AAA_123`, `ABC_sdf12343` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did stupid things.

I just add `^` and `&`.

I means from `"[A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}", "123_aaa"` to `"^[A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}$", "123_aaa"`and from `~*` to `~`.

Test your regex here http://www.regexpal.com/ before trying if you are a novice at regex.

It works perfectly!